# Jquery - change value on change input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onchange

I need to change input field value on other input change value.

I write:

```
$('#myself').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#choose').modal('hide');
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseThree').collapse('show');

    $('#b_email').on('change', function () {
        var p = $('#b_email').val();
        $("r_email").val(p);
    });

    $('#b_first_name').on('change', function () {
        var p = $('#b_first_name').val();
        $("r_first_name").val(p);
    });

    $('#b_last_name').on('change', function () {
        var p = $('#b_last_name').val();
        $("r_last_name").val(p);
    });

    $("message").val('No message');
    $("voucher_from").val('MYSELF');
});
```

[image]

So as you can see value dont change in first form when I change value in second form. WHy?

How i can trigger that?

Comment: Provide jsfiddle with whole code.

Comment: Every time you click on `#myself` a new `change` handler will be added to `#b_email`, `#b_first_name` and `#b_last_name`. And check your selectors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi there,**

You want to fill this input with the value p. Right? How does the code where to place this value?

Try making this 
 `$("r_first_name").val(p);`
to an class and give the input a class. May be worth a try. 
 `$(".r_first_name").val(p);`

Comment: thanks ... I forgot '.' and '#' ... but how to at every keypress change value of input field?

Comment: try using `onkeyup`